# Saving multiple nested objects with a single request on parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have two Classes, and Email class and and EmailAssignment class. The Email class saves an email address and a createdBy pointer to a user. The EmailAssignment class holds a pointer to an Email instance and a pointer to a Project instance.

What I'd like to do is batch save all of my email classes and email assignment classes in one request. Is this possible?

For example, when I query EmailAssignment classes I can includeKey["email"] to retrieve the nested pointer object as well. I'm looking for the inverse of this for saving objects.

Can it be done? I'm working with ios client, but I doubt that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PFObject.saveAll()` saves an array of objects.  Maybe more to the point: when saving any object, parse will save any dirty (new or changed) objects pointed to by the object being saved.

Because of that, you may be able to limit your saveAll to a smaller set, to just the "from" side of the relations.